# Tools for presentations with Xcode

Tags: mac, xcode

Have you got any tools you use for presentations with Xcode? I'm preparing for some live 'showdowns'. Anything is welcome - mouse pointer enhancers, fast typing with snippets, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Omnidazzle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnidazzle/) is nice. I can't really think of anything else... Try using a clipboard saver to paste faster than you could type and still seem professional.