# Xcode tools for presentation of development's tutorials

Tags: software-recommendation, xcode, keynote

During WWDC we can see Xcode screencast code presentations where they highlight portions of Xcode and type text faster.

I've research a number of popular tools used for typing screencasts like: [PlayItAgainSam](https://github.com/rfk/playitagainsam) and [PlayerPiano](https://github.com/wearpants/playerpiano) also I've read this question [Tools for presentations with Xcode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17453/tools-for-presentations-with-xcode) that recommend the defunct tool Omnidazzle

Does anyone know a tool for making presentations based on Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

They don't use any special tools. 
At WWDC they press Control and scroll to zoom in. That behavior can be enabled under Accessibility in System Preferences. 
For the code they use Snippets feature of Xcode to expand prepared pieces of code.

Answer (score 1):

QuickTime Player works well in any app for me. Open it, select File -> New Screen Recording and then just follow the on-screen instructions. It will record a video of the entire screen. It won't work with copy protected DVDs though.

Comment: You can also select part of the screen too.

Comment: I have used Quicktime, but the video of my typing is not as fluid as we see in Apple's demo. I was wondering if there was some plugin to xcode to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[LICECap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) a and very simple and lightweight software to record GIF. It is open source as well.

Comment: I use LICECap almost every day, awesome tool. But it's not for this kind of task